# How to set PlaceHolder in select2 for multiselect false after select2 reset and before we select any option

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-select2

While Loading Page I am getting all the Subject Names and storing list into an Array

```
subjectArray[];
```

after that i am binding that list into the select2 like as

```
$('#ddl_Subject').select2({
            multiple: false,
            data: subjectArray,
        initSelection: function (element, callback) {
            }
});

<div class="col-sm-3">
    <select id="ddl_Subject" class="" data-isdynamic="true">
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" id="hf_Subject">
</div>
```

Scene 1:- By default dropdown should display placeholder,

scene 2:- On change of Select2 i am copying the selected value into a textArea and Once the text is copied to that target textArea again the select2 will get reset by mentioning

```
initSelection: function (element, callback) {
        }
```

but it should show the PlaceHolder before and after selecting a subject "Select Subject".

If I set multiple:true, then placeHolder will work

Comment: $("#yourID").select2({
    placeholder: "Please Select ",
    allowClear: true
});

Comment: @Ricky i am already clearing the list, using the init Selection mentioned above. as much i read we cannot kept placeholder if its multiple false, i cannot add an option cause it will appear into the list of select2.